# Converting SQL to Doctrine DBAL or createQuery()

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dbal, createquery

How can I rewrite this query to Doctrine DBAL query or better to createQuery() structure? When I used createQuery() "data_last" was not recognized as date but as string and generated errors. Maybe better solution would be internal left join and calculation done on symfony side? ROUND function is not recognised by Doctrine.

```
   $sql='SELECT
    q.fund_id   AS tfi,
    f.fundName     AS name,

    ( SELECT `date`
      FROM quotes
      WHERE DATE_SUB( "'. $sToday .'", INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) <=  `date` AND `fund_id` = `tfi`
      ORDER BY `date` DESC
      LIMIT 1)           AS date_last,

    ( SELECT `value`
      FROM quotes
      WHERE `fund_id` = `tfi` AND `date` = `date_last`
      LIMIT 1)           AS value_last,


    ( SELECT `date`
      FROM quotes
      WHERE DATE_SUB( date_last, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) <=  `date` AND `fund_id` = `tfi`
      ORDER BY  `date` ASC
      LIMIT 1)           AS date_1m,

    ( SELECT `value`
      FROM quotes
      WHERE `fund_id` = `tfi` AND `date` = `date_1m`
      LIMIT 1)           AS value_1m,

    ( SELECT ROUND( (value_last-value_1m)/value_1m*100, 2) ) AS chg_1m

    FROM quotes q
    LEFT JOIN funds  f
    ON ( q.fund_id = f.id )
    GROUP BY q.fund_id
    ORDER BY f.fundName';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoa, I wouldn't waste any time trying to rewrite query this complexity. You're definitely better off with Doctrine [Native SQL](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/native-sql.html)

Comment: thank you for opinion, how about mine subqueries instead of left joins? what would be better solution?